# How to use link (href) in specific part at php echo?

Tags: php, html

I want to make underline at specific part using href in php.
Please help..

Here is my code..

```
             echo "Welcome " . $row1['name'] . "Sir  ";

//I want to make underline only this part: $row1['name'];
```

Comment: Oh.. It works !! Thank You!!

Answer (score 2):

You can actually put `anchor tag` directly inside your `php echo`

```
echo "Welcome <a href='#yourlink'>" . $row1['name'] . "</a> Sir ";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo " Welcome <a href='hyperlink'>" . $row1['name'] . "</a> Sir "; 
?>
```

This will work, without any flow